# firestore path for cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to work on sending push notifications for any new message in my flutter app using firebase cloud functions without any success.
I wrote code to save any new message data to firestore in this path(messages/groupChatId/groupChatId/DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()).

```
 var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .doc(groupChatId)
      .collection(groupChatId)
     .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
```

After that I wrote cloud functions starting to indicate the path;

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("messages/groupChatId/groupChatId/DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()").onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {...}
```

Is this the right way to read data in the path? Or do I have to use curly brackets somewhere in the path? Would somebody please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made it work by changing the path like this;

```
exports.sendNotification = 
functions.firestore.document("messages/{groupChatId}/chats/{chat}").onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {...}
```